# Creating and assigning nested models always even if not through create controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a simple workshop booking app, where I have the workshop and it's seats, in which every user can fill out a form and define the number of seats, which through goes through this, passing the workshop_id and seat number since i want it to always be from 1 to 30 in each workshop room instead of being just by id.

```
def new
  @workshop = Workshop.new
  respond_with(@workshop)
end

def create
  @workshop = Workshop.new(workshop_params)

  i = 1

  while i < @workshop.number_of_seats.to_i + 1 do
    @workshop.seats.new(:seat_number => i)
    i = i + 1
  end

  @workshop.save
  respond_with(@workshop)
end
```

This works when I create it inside the form, but if I do it through active admin, or just by seeding the app with 5 workshops, it will not use the same create block to generate those seatings.

Any suggestion on how to move this maybe to some after_create logic? Or simplyfing this so I dont have this code in a controller

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `while` cycles usage isn't the ruby way. Rubists prefer iterators, so you can refactor this:

```
i = 1

while i < @workshop.number_of_seats.to_i + 1 do
  @workshop.seats.new(:seat_number => i)
  i = i + 1
end
```

to

```
@workshop.number_of_seats.times do |seat_number|
  @workshop.seats.new(seat_number: seat_number + 1)
end
```

And yes, you probably want to move this code outside of your controller. Maybe the better option is to use `after_save` instead of `after_create`(because you will be able to change seats number). And don't forget to validate `number_of_seats` attribute, as you probably don't want it to be very big.

So your callback could be:

```
after_save :ensure_seats

def ensure_seats
  if number_of_seats > seats.count
    (seats.count...number_of_seats).each do |seat_number|
      seats.create(seat_number: seat_number + 1)
    end
  elsif number_of_seats < seats.count
    seats.where("seat_number > ?", number_of_seats).destroy_all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should clean up the new seat initialization code:

```
@workshop.number_of_seats.times do |i|
  @workshop.seats.new(seat_number: (i + 1))
end
```

Now as I understand your question, you want the above to happen if it's not through the controller.

Then I suggest you remove that controller code altogether and in your Workshop model's class you do the following:

```
class Workshop < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :initialize_seats

  def initialize_seats
    return if seats.present?

    number_of_seats.times do |i|
      self.seats.new(seat_number: (i + 1))
    end
  end
end
```

Depending on your use case you might need a `before_create` callback rather than `before_save`. OR you could even shift that to an `after_create` callback if it suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, your answer is as great as the other one, but I think he pointed more issues to a starter rubyist so I will accept him to be the definite answer